# unable to get dynamic content in web 8

Tags: web8, broker, dynamic-linking, sdl-tridion, webservice

I am getting the following error when I try to access some pages:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> System.Exception: Invalid TcmUri: ##componentUri##   at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Model.TcmUri.Parse(String uri)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: System.Exception: Invalid
>   TcmUri: ##componentUri##   at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Model.TcmUri.Parse(String uri)

Please find the stack trace below:

> [FormatException: System.Exception: Invalid TcmUri: ##componentUri##
>   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Model.TcmUri.Parse(String uri)]
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Model.TcmUri.Parse(String uri) +822
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationAssemblerImpl.GetContent(String
>   componentURI, String componentTemplateURI, IDictionary`2
>   renderingParameters) +51
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.WebUI.Presentation.ComponentPresentation.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +127
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +80
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +80
>   ASP.master_master.__RendermainForm(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control
>   parameterContainer) in e:\Sites\Websites
>   New\torkusa.com\master.master:438
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +263
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +11827669
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +47
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +80
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +50    ASP.master_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in e:\Sites\Websites New\torkusa.com\master.master:58
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +263
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +80
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +160    System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +39
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +80
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +8921

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The exception seems to be self explanatory. You are passing an invalid tcm uri.

A tcm uri is of the following format: tcm:*publicationId*-*itemId*-*itemType*

Examples:

- Publication,  tcm:0-1-1
- Component, tcm:1-1234
- Page, tcm:1-12-64

Comment: but here uri of the component format is ok still it is giving this error.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing some TBB or Storage/Deployer extension that converts "##componentUri##" token into a proper tcm ID on publish?

Comment: Issue is resolved now There are some wrong code is there in one of the TBB. I have commented it and it works fine after then. Thx

Comment: To help others, please put that as an answer, and accept it.